# Program suddenly has many bugs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, avaudiorecorder

I have been building a program for the past few months. I finally got to the point where everything was working great. The program has been built for iOS 5 from the beginning. And i just checked on things that i thought i had cemented in and that were working fine when i checked a few days ago. But now everything is acting goofy. My recorder stopped working. Not sure in what area. My seeker's values arnt changing as they should. Playback of the recording is not working. The recorder used to take a second to load up where it would freeze the screen then start, now it is instantaneous which i find odd. Im sorry if im being vague but im totally stumped. The record button sets off a timer after the record command. In the timer there is an if statement, which has many clauses, one being myRecorder.isRecording == NO, and yet the if statement acts as if the conditions are met and executes the code inside, despite the recorder being told to record right before the timer even started. I AM BAFFLED. Please help. Thanks

Code for record button:
- (IBAction)record:(id)sender {
        //[myPlayer play];

```
if ([sender tag] == 2){
    [self stop];
    [sender setTag:1];
    [sender setTitle:@"Record"];
    [sender setEnabled:NO];
    NSLog(@"Tag is 2");
}else{
    if ([myPlayer isPlaying]){
        [myPlayer pause];
        [myPlayer setCurrentTime:0];
    }
    anotherControl = 0; 
    theToolbar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [theToolbar setTintColor:myColor];
    [theToolbar setAlpha:.5];
    [controlSong setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    beatPackTable.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    beatPackTable.hidden = YES;
    onScreenTut.text = @"(Hold phone to your face and begin. When finished recording, hit the stop button)";
    recordCover.titleLabel.text = @"Recording";
    recordCover.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    recordCover.hidden = NO;
    NSString *docsDir;
    myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    myDate = [NSDate date];
    seekerTwo.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    homeButton.enabled = NO;
    tracksButton.enabled = NO;
    tutButton.enabled = NO;
    previewBeatTwo.enabled = NO;
    previewPauseTwo.enabled = NO;

    /*    
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
     [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
     NSString *myDate2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]];
     */    
    //    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    //                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();


    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.caf",myDate,control]];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityLow],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;



    myNewRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    } else {
        [myNewRecorder prepareToRecord];}




    seeker.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    voiceVolumeControl.enabled =YES;
    recordButton.enabled = NO;

    stopButton.enabled = YES;


    myPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    [myNewRecorder record];
    [myPlayer play];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

if ([sender tag] == 1){
    [sender setTitle:@"End"];
    [sender setTag:2];

}}
NSLog(@"%@",myDate);
}
```

Code for timer:

-(void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer{

```
    if ([myNewRecorder isRecording]) {
        [seeker setValue:myPlayer.currentTime/myPlayer.duration animated:YES];}

    if ([myPlayer2 isPlaying])
    {
        [seeker setValue:myPlayer2.currentTime/myPlayer2.duration animated:YES];
    }

    if ([myPlayer isPlaying] && myPlayer2.isPlaying == NO && myNewRecorder.isRecording == NO && isNotepadOpen == NO && anotherControl == 0) {
        [myPlayer stop];
        myPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        [seeker setValue:0];
        playButton.enabled = YES;
        stopButton.enabled = NO;
        NSLog(@"Its the timer for some reason");
    }

    if ([myNewRecorder isRecording] || [myPlayer isPlaying] || [myPlayer2 isPlaying]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    }else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
    }
    if ([myPlayer isPlaying]){
        [seekerTwo setValue:myPlayer.currentTime/myPlayer.duration animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: code please. also, can you format your question?

Comment: Can you go back to a known good working version using whatever source control system you use, and then work forward from there ?

Comment: Ill post some code, but its pretty intricate so i dont know how much itll help. And ill see if i can do that

Comment: I dont really know if i can go back to a previous version. I dont know when this started to happen exactly, but i have a back up i made a little while ago that i know worked that i will try.

Comment: When coding you'd benefit from a source control system such as GIT or Subversion. It would allow you to have easily accessible backups of every version of your code, compare differences, and much more. Always, always use one, even if you're coding on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the advice im fairly new to programming. And i dont have time machine set up :/.. 
And i guess my question would be, what could cause things to act so weird? though thats extremely ambiguous.

Comment: See my answer (and others) to that question on Programmers SE: [“It was working yesterday, I swear!” What can you do?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/104900/1033)

Comment: Does anyone think it could have something to do with upgrading to the GM? I dont remember exactly when i last tested this area of the app so i dont know if it was working after i upgraded but has any experienced any problems since they upgraded that could be related?

Comment: -1 for missing code formatting.

Comment: This is unrelated i think, but i cant access the class reference files now. When i click on one and get prompted to sign into my developer account, it says the input is locked. and when i try to type in my password nothing shows up and i just get annoying beeps. Ive tried restarting xcode but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer (and others) to that question on Programmers SE: [“It was working yesterday, I swear!” What can you do?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/104900/1033)

Basically, find what has changed since the sudden bugs, maybe a new delivery of iOS 5, Xcode or an external library that your software uses.